# How do I take a URL stored in a variable in JS and pass it to HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am a beginner so I'm sure this is probably obvious.

I have an API call which finds current news for a location which I have stored in a variable called newsUrl. I wish to show this in my HTML file within a modal.

here is the code for my modal

```
<div id="newsModal" class="modal">   
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-heading">News</h4>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close"  aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
     
        <tr>
          
          <td><p id="txtNews"></p></td>

        </tr>
        
      
     
  </table>
  </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have tried the following code within my JS file

```
newsUrl = result['data'][0]['url'];
          newsImage = result['data'][0]['image'];
          newsTitle = result['data'][0]['title'];
          

          newsLink = ('<a href="//'+newsUrl+'" target=_blank ></a>');
             
          $('#txtNews').html(newsLink);
```

No errors in the console.

Comment: newUrl, newsImage, newsTitle and newsLink are not defined as variables? e.g. var newsUrl = result['data'][0]['url']; Is this the full JS code?

Comment: they were declared as variables but thank you I have now found an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: $('#txtNews').append(newsLink);

Comment: thank you I have now found an alternative solution.